# Simple-salesforce: perform a bulk insert on a lookup field

Tags: bulk-api, python, simple-salesforce

I am attempting to perform a bulk insert to a custom object in salesforce using the simple-salesforce library.

I have a lookup field with a the api endpoint 'Account_Name__c', along with a few others. Here's a sample of what I'm sending through:

```
[{'ID__c': '123456789',
  'Date__c': '2022-12-21',
  'Total_Transactions__c': 1,
  'Amount__c': -492.81,
  'Account_Name__c': 'a1j1234567'}]
```

I've tried to insert with the account name, it returns this error:

```
[{'success': False,
  'created': False,
  'id': None,
  'errors': [{'statusCode': 'FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION',
    'message': 'Account Name: id value of incorrect type: a1j1234567',
    'fields': ['Account_Name__c']}]}]
```

If I pull that field out of there, the insert goes through fine but of course doesn't update the field that is a lookup linking it to the account object.

Is there a way to do this using simple-salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert records while matching a lookup field against a non-Id field on the parent object, you must structure your input data to define which field you're matching against. It won’t work to provide non-Id data inline in the relationship field.  These semantics are set by the Bulk API, rather than `simple_salesforce` itself.

`simple_salesforce` has an [example](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#using-bulk) in its Bulk documentation that addresses this goal in the context of an update operation. It's the third example as of this writing, reproduced below:

```python
data = [
      {'Id': '0000000000AAAAA', 'Custom_Object__r': {'Email__c':'examplenew@example.com'}},
      {'Id': '0000000000BBBBB', 'Custom_Object__r': {'Email__c': 'testnew@test.com'}}
    ]

sf.bulk.Contact.update(data,batch_size=10000,use_serial=True)
```

The salient points here are:

1. You must provide a nested JSON object with the field name and value for the field you want to match against. The key in the top-level object is the relationship name - *not* the name of the relationship field. For custom fields, this will end in `__r`, not `__c`.
2. The target field, that you wish to match on the related object, must be indexed.

See [Relationship Fields in Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_rel_fields.htm) for more details on the Bulk API's semantics.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I definitely read this example but have read through the documentation so many times I skimmed it inadvertently. That makes a lot of sense, now I'll just need to figure out how to get a nested json inside the request!

Comment: Hey @DavidReed, I posted this in a new thread since it's not the original question here. I was wondering if you already know how to transform a pandas dataframe into the desired format for uploading to the bulk API? See the new post here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953798/how-do-i-create-a-specific-nesting-format-json-or-dictionary-from-a-pandas-dataf)

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t - I don’t use Pandas myself.

Comment: no worries, thank you for letting me know!

Comment: An updated answer to this thread can be found here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/392929/simple-salesforce-is-there-a-way-to-bulk-insert-data-on-a-lookup-field-without/392931#392931