# Simple-Salesforce: is there a way to bulk insert data on a lookup field without an external ID?

Tags: bulk-api, python, simple-salesforce

I previously posted this question: [Simple-salesforce: perform a bulk insert on a lookup field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/392833/simple-salesforce-perform-a-bulk-insert-on-a-lookup-field)

In that thread I got the documentation answer for how to perform an update based on an external ID.

In the use case I'm going over, we have our standard account object and then we have another object which has the account name from account as a lookup field. I am attempting to update the lookup field in an API call using simplesalesforce, but it is proving to be challenging.

Here is what I've tried sending through bulk.insert and error I recieved:

```
final_insert = [{'ID__c': '1234567',
  'Date__c': '2022-12-27',
  'Total_Transactions__c': 1,
  'Amount__c': 50.50,
  'Account_Name__r': {'Name': 'Foo LLC'}}]
```

error:

```
[{'success': False,
  'created': False,
  'id': None,
  'errors': [{'statusCode': 'INVALID_FIELD',
    'message': 'Field name provided, Name is not an External ID or indexed field for Account',
    'fields': []}]}]
```

Very confused about this one because "Name" **IS** in fact an indexed field!

I've been digging for an entire day on this and can't seem to find a very clear path.

What I'd ideally like to do is update the lookup field for the business name in my custom object based directly on the account Id. This is how it looks when I attempt that:

```
final_insert = [{'ID__c': '1234567',
  'Date__c': '2022-12-27',
  'Total_Transactions__c': 1,
  'Amount__c': 50.50,
  'Account_Name__r': {'Id': 'a1234567'}}]
```

and this is the error:

```
[{'success': False,
  'created': False,
  'id': None,
  'errors': [{'statusCode': 'INVALID_FIELD',
    'message': 'Field name provided, Id is not an External ID or indexed field for Account',
    'fields': []}]}]
```

so to summarize what I'm attempting:

1. update a custom object with lookup field referencing the name of the account object
2. use the account Id to perform the lookup
3. perform this by bulk insert in simple-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

I found the following thread:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000QzBOQA0
The answer in the thread says
"Go to the record type and from the address bar, you should see something like this - https://xxx.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypefields.jsp?id=01220000000VCdE and copy the ID from there."

This lead me to wonder if I should be using the account record type id, when I changed the request like this:

```
final_insert = [{'ID__c': '1234567',
  'Date__c': '2022-12-27',
  'Total_Transactions__c': 1,
  'Amount__c': 50.50,
  'Account_Name__c': 'recordtypeid1234567'}]
```

I got a successful update and was able to confirm that the new inserted record is linking back to the account page on the lookup field.